# HTML its not rendering from React JS (Localhost APACHE)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, apache

from a week now i'am trying to fix my issue . I have created a React Application with :

`npm create react-app`

And after that i have tried to make a build with :

`npm run build`

Normally everything went well .From the Command Prompt i have created a build folder. Inside i have created my `.htacess` file with this prop:

**.htacess**

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

I have made some changes to my `package.json` :

**package.json**

```
"homepage": "http://localhost/build-interface",
```

And finally i have done some last changes to my `index.html` inside of the 
`/build/index.html`

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/build-interface/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/build-interface/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/build-interface/static/css/2.df50b353.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/build-interface/static/css/main.e73dfb08.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>!function (l) { function e(e) { for (var r, t, n = e[0], o = e[1], u = e[2], i = 0, f = []; i < n.length; i++)t = n[i], c[t] && f.push(c[t][0]), c[t] = 0; for (r in o) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, r) && (l[r] = o[r]); for (s && s(e); f.length;)f.shift()(); return p.push.apply(p, u || []), a() } function a() { for (var e, r = 0; r < p.length; r++) { for (var t = p[r], n = !0, o = 1; o < t.length; o++) { var u = t[o]; 0 !== c[u] && (n = !1) } n && (p.splice(r--, 1), e = i(i.s = t[0])) } return e } var t = {}, c = { 1: 0 }, p = []; function i(e) { if (t[e]) return t[e].exports; var r = t[e] = { i: e, l: !1, exports: {} }; return l[e].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, i), r.l = !0, r.exports } i.m = l, i.c = t, i.d = function (e, r, t) { i.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, { enumerable: !0, get: t }) }, i.r = function (e) { "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 }) }, i.t = function (r, e) { if (1 & e && (r = i(r)), 8 & e) return r; if (4 & e && "object" == typeof r && r && r.__esModule) return r; var t = Object.create(null); if (i.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: r }), 2 & e && "string" != typeof r) for (var n in r) i.d(t, n, function (e) { return r[e] }.bind(null, n)); return t }, i.n = function (e) { var r = e && e.__esModule ? function () { return e.default } : function () { return e }; return i.d(r, "a", r), r }, i.o = function (e, r) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r) }, i.p = "/build-interface/"; var r = window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || [], n = r.push.bind(r); r.push = e, r = r.slice(); for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++)e(r[o]); var s = n; a() }([])</script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/build-interface/static/js/2.dac00856.chunk.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/build-interface/static/js/main.75794944.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have done it a couple of times and try different things , but the result stays the same . Even i have rendered a clean `React App` without nothing inside ... it will not launch . 
The problem mainly is that i can see my script is launched to the network (**APACHE localhost**) , but is not shown in the browser . I can also get my `console.log` and the `CSS` (i know that , because i see that my background is grey) , but for the rest ... empty page . I will be very happy if someone can help me fix that issue .

**Here is the result visually :**

[image]

**P.S.**

I have a two clues from where the problem is coming :

1. My Routing isn't right and page cannot find the right path to display it .
2. There is something wrong with the `localhost` and i cannot render the app from the `Apache` server.

**UPDATE**

By request of @AKX i will post my routing :

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import './styles/index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import Select from './pages/SelectionPage';
import Summary from './pages/SummaryPage';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const Root = () =>  (

<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/select" component={Select} />
        <Route path="/summary" component={Summary} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  )

ReactDOM.render( <Root/>, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And further more :

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from '../pages/HomePage';
import '../styles/App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <div id='blur-overlay'></div>    
        <div className='mainContainer'>
           <Home/> 
        </div>
      </div>

          );
        }
      }

export default App;
```

And further more i will not post the rest of the code , but here is a part of it :

**HomePage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Switch } from 'react-router'
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import BarcodeReader from 'react-barcode-reader';
import 'moment-timezone';
import adv from '../img/add-01.svg'
import '../styles/App.css';

import Warning from '../components/PopupWarning'
import Ok from '../components/PopupOk'
import Alert from '../components/PopupAlert'
import SelectionPage from './SelectionPage'
import Header from '../components/Header';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';



// import connection from '../mysql/connection'

const dateToFormat = new Date();

console.log('this is the home page');

class Home extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      okRedirect: false,
      modalOK: false
    }

    this.handleScan = this.handleScan.bind(this)



  }

  handleScan(data) {

    this.setState({
      modalOK: true
    })

    setTimeout( function() {
      this.setState({ okRedirect: true });
    }.bind(this) , 1500)
  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.okRedirect) {
      return (

        <SelectionPage/>
      );

    }

    return (

      <Router>
        <Switch>
        <div className='home'>
      <Header/>
          <div>
            <BarcodeReader
              onError={this.handleError}
              onScan={this.handleScan}
            />
            <p>{this.state.result}</p>
          </div>
          <div className='home-main-content'>
            <div className='motd'>
              <h1>Message of the day :</h1>
              <br />
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu ipsum elementum, maximus ligula ut, pretium libero. Nullam quis nulla lectus. Morbi tristique enim eu enim scelerisque suscipit. Curabitur fringilla diam nec ipsum tempor sodales. Sed in lectus imperdiet, bibendum enim et, faucibus quam. In quis magna bibendum, porta massa et, cursus massa. Suspendisse sem tellus, pulvinar vel sollicitudin id, tempor dictum nunc. Fusce ultricies, nisi ut sollicitudin tincidunt, nibh nulla viverra dolor, et dignissim eros odio eu elit. Nulla eu tincidunt tellus.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu ipsum elementum, maximus ligula ut, pretium libero. Nullam quis nulla lectus. Morbi tristique enim eu enim scelerisque suscipit. Curabitur fringilla diam nec ipsum tempor sodales. Sed in lectus imperdiet, bibendum enim et, faucibus quam. In quis magna bibendum, porta massa et, cursus massa. Suspendisse sem tellus, pulvinar vel sollicitudin id, tempor dictum nunc.
          </div>
            <aside>


              <div className='clock'>
                <span className='clock-hour'><Moment
                  date={dateToFormat}
                  format='HH'
                  interval={30000}
                />
                </span>
                <span className='clock-min'>
                  <Moment
                    date={dateToFormat}
                    format='mm'
                    interval={30000}
                  />
                </span>
                <span className='clock-date'>
                  <Moment
                    date={dateToFormat}
                    format=' ddd , DD MMM'
                  />
                </span>

              </div>

              <div className='home-info'>
                <h1 id='a-off-h'>Avaible Officers:</h1>
                <ul className='a-off'>
                  {''}
                  <li><p>John Doe</p></li>
                  <li><p>Smith John</p></li>
                  <li><p>Nicolas M.</p></li>
                  <li><p>David Reanaers</p></li>
                  <li><p>Georgi Mumdzhiev</p></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </aside>
          </div>

          <p className='qr'>
            <div className='onlineStatus'>
              <div class="nuclear">
                <span className='statusOnlyName'>online</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <span className='advert-text'>
              MyShootLog is avaible on :
                          </span>
            <span className='par'><img id='advert' src={adv} alt='advert' /></span>
          </p>
          <Alert />
          <Ok {...this.state} />
          <Warning />



<Footer/>
        </div>

</Switch>
      </Router>

    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: The app is clearly being rendered judging from stuff being printed to console – routing might be the issue here. Please show us some of your routing code, too.

Comment: @AKX I have updated a part of my code . You can check it out in the main post .

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, you need to pass a `ReverseProxy` through apache to the node server.

Meaning, you would need to execute `npm start` and by default I believe it's port 3000 on localhost to see your site served up with ReactJS, through apache. Otherwise, you're just viewing the static HTML pages with apache, and React is doing nothing. Feel free to add me on Skype and I can show you what I mean - danbirlem

Comment: "the node server is only for development" oh my bad, I thought this person was clearly developing a node project. Thanks for the pointless downvote.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a pointless downvote; I'd call exposing the CRA development server to the internet (quoting the vote-down FAQ) "an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect".

Comment: Sorry if I sounded bitter. I can see the concern, but by nature of the question, wouldn't the apache server OP is running would also be exposed to the internet?

Comment: I fail to see how running the node server (for development here) would be significantly different from running the apache server, in regards to exposure to the internet.

Comment: Development servers tend to expose tracebacks and other debugging info (not to mention they usually run non-minified/non-optimized code that's easier to debug), which can be a security risk. Some development servers even allow direct remote code execution.